# Chrome Extension - Turn my default Popup into a Sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

I have a functional default Popup and now I want to instead inject that popup.html with an iframe into the Dom. Have it toggled to show and hide with the browseraction onclick. I can't find any good solution on this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)
or execute script that add the iframe dynamically via the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)  method

Running javascript from contentscript is the best way to manipulate the DOM